# What are the security concerns when connecting to a WiFi network?

Tags: network, wifi

I connected my phone to a protected Wifi network that is not my own. Can anyone accessing the same network be considered a threat on my mobile device? Is it easier for hackers connected to the same Wifi network to access my mobile data?  If so, how can I protect my device?

Unlike other questions I have read on this website, the network is secured but more than one person have access to it and i'm not only concerned about emails but all data found on my device in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People on the same network can read your unencrypted web traffic. They probably won't be able to access your phone data unless you have apps that open up your phone to that (FTP/SSH apps, for example)

If you want to protect the data you send over the web, only use visit SSL (HTTPS) pages while on this network.

Comment: Also few month ago, whatsapp use to have some issue and the messages, pictures, etc, could be caught with some sniffer or an application.